# Performing two (clashing) interpolations on one string

Tags: regex, perl

I have an interpolate function that replaces `%foo` with the value from `$HV{'default'}{'foo'}` and `%foo.bar` from `$HV{foo}{bar}`:

```
sub interpolate {
    my $work = "@_";
    $work =~ s/\%(\w+)\.(\w+)/$HV{$1}{$2}/g;
    $work =~ s/\%(\w+)/$HV{'default'}{$1}/g;
    return $work;
}
```

However if `$HV{'foo'}{'bar'}` contains a `%` character, the second operation matches it which is not what I want.  My first fix was to change all occurrences of `%foo` into `%default.foo` with

```
$work =~ s/\%(\w+)/%default\.$1/g;
$work =~ s/\%(\w+)\.(\w+)/$HV{$1}{$2}/g;
```

But this changes `%foo.bar` into `%default.foo.bar`.  Is there a way to do what I want without re-doing my hash?

Also for bonus credit I'd be interested in a regular expression that would match `%A.very.long.and.deeply.nested.hash.value` with the corresponding value to make it work with any hash.

Comment: I am unsure what you actually want. Does $hash{foo}{bar} ever contain things that still need to be replaced? If not, you could simply return if first match replaced something, like `return $work if $work =~ s/\%(\w+)\.(\w+)/$HV{$1}{$2}/g;`. Otherwise, I do not know what it is you want exactly. Especially, the last sentence is a mystery to me.

Comment: For the bonus question, what is "the corresponding value" from the hash?

Comment: You would need to iterate over the work string, finding the longer of `%x.y` and `%x` at each point, then replacing that value, and continuing after that.  As it stands, each `g` suffix does that for the pattern it is attached to, but the second pattern rescans the modified text — doing the extra substitutions you don't want.  You may have to make a more complex match pattern (`m/\%(\w+)(?:\.(\w+))/` or thereabouts), and execute code in the replacement part (`e` modifier) depending on whether `$2` is defined or not. …As shown in @melpomene's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32160481/15168)!

Comment: Is this a problem that may have been solved by the myriad templating systems? (Template::Toolkit, Text::Template, HTML::Template, Template, Template::Simple, Template::Tiny, and so on).

Comment: No $hash{foo}{bar} doesn't contain things that need to be replaced but sometimes it contains a URI escaped string like "help%20me" that I want printed as is without the %20me being matched by the second line.  Its for a template module which allows the programmer to load various hashes and arrays into the %HV hash by passing references and the template writer to access them with the corresponding %hash.key syntax.  The %{$HV{'default'}} hash contains global variables and the ${foo}{bar} contains variables obtained from looping through an array of hashes so I want to access both.

Comment: For the bonus question I was referring to implementing a functionality similar to Template::Toolkit where you can pass a hash of hash of hashs or whatever and just access it with the right amount of dots.

Comment: And DavidO, yup you busted me. I've looked into all the CPAN solutions and it's partly a learning exercise and partly that I really dislike their syntax. Also I haven't found on that allows me to break up the parsing and printing stages so that my script can decide whether to load up a given hash or not depending on whether its mentioned in the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to do a single traversal of the string, not two in a row:

```
$work =~ s{%(\w+)(?:\.(\w+))?}{
    defined $2
        ? $HV{$1}{$2}
        : $HV{default}{$1}
}eg;
```

---

To fix your other approach, you could change your regex to

```
$work =~ s/%(\w+)(?!\.\w)/%default.$1/g;
```

to only replace `%foo` if it's not followed by `.bar`.

---

Bonus credit: Assuming you want to replace `%foo.bar.baz` by `$HV{foo}{bar}{baz}`, this can be done as follows:

```
sub lookup {
    my ($cur, @keys) = @_;
    $cur = $cur->{$_} for @keys;
    return $cur;
}

s{%(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)}{
    lookup(\%HV, split(/\./, $1))
}eg;
```

Comment: Brilliant!  That fix to my second approach has doubled my regex powers too as I didn't know about the ! in regexes.  Thanks a bunch you really went over and above on this one.